# Do HttpWebRequest have any vulnerabilities that can infect OS

Tags: c#, security, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest, webclient

My question is, with below way of harvesting web, can the program running OS get infected with any possible way ?

The os is windows server 2008 r2 or windows 7 sp1

c# 4.5

Here the method i am using

I am just looking answer of any possible way of getting infected via any virus or any security vulnerability

I mean is below way 100% secure ?

```
   using (System.Net.WebClient webClnt = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(srQueryRequest);

            if (srProxyHost != "none")
            {
                webClnt.Proxy = proxy;
                webClnt.Credentials = proxy.Credentials;
                request.Proxy = proxy;
            }

            request.Timeout = irTimeOut * 1000;

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream strumien = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strumien))
                    {
                        string srResult = sr.ReadToEnd();                            
                    }
                        }
                    }
                }
          }
```

Comment: What are you doing with `srResult`?

Comment: nothing. just text operations such as replace, save to file, substring etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to security, that depends what you do with the returned string. If it cointains javascript and you exectute it in a browser, you could in theory pick up something nasty.

That aside, the code is something of a mess.

WebClient ( a wrapper of webrequest)is not used, the above code could be condensed down to:

```
   using (System.Net.WebClient webClnt = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
       webClnt.proxy = proxy;
       var srResult = webClient.DownloadString(srQueryRequest);
    }
```

Comment: i am not executing the string. just text string operations. also i wonder that any possibility from proxies ? i don't trust proxies

Comment: also i checked and it does not have any timeout feature. i mean webclient ?

Comment: If you are just performing string manipulation you will be fine, even if the proxies return something nasty, if you dont exectute it. About timeout, correct that is not implemented in webclient wrapper, so either just use the webrequest (web client does nothing in your code) or extend the webclient class